# Capture mass email responses in lead

Tags: leads, activities, campaign, massemailmessage, mass-email

I have many leads and i want to send them introduction email about our company services. I will use Mass email function of Salesforce. My question is if any lead response on the email, can we capture that response under activity history.
Like we do with email to case option.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to copy your email to salesforce unique mail id the BCC field while you are triggering your bulk email so that whenever an receiver sends out the response it will get attached to the activity history.